# Learn probablistic rank order from lots paired comparisons

Tags: bayesian, ordinal-data, paired-data, conjoint-analysis, stochastic-ordering

Suppose I have $k$ different unknown probability distributions (e.g. $A$, $B$, ...) and I have data that provide examples of draws from pairs of distributions (e.g. $a_1$ and $c_1$, then $b_2$ and $d_2$, ...) where the subscript is the index of the sampled pair.  However, for each pair drawn, the actual value from each distribution is not given; instead which of the 2 values is greater is given (e.g. $a_1<c_1$, $b_2>d_2$, ...)

From these data, how can we make use of the implied (and explicit) ordering in the data to predict the probability that a sample from a first given distribution will be higher than the sample from a given second distribution (e.g. $Pr(a_i>b_i)$, $Pr(a_i>c_i)$, or $Pr(b_i>c_i)$, etc.)

Or, would it be possible to calculate a probablistic rank ordering of the distributions?  For, example if $k=3$ the result could look something like this for distribution $A$:

$$Pr(rank(A)=1) = 0.01$$
$$Pr(rank(A)=2) = 0.80$$
$$Pr(rank(A)=3) = 0.19$$
where the $Pr(rank(A)=1)$ is interpreted as the probability that a draw from the $A$ would be higher than a draw from any other distribution, and *not* the $rank$ of a matrix.  In the case of $k=3$, $Pr(rank(A)=3)$ would represent the probability that the sample drawn from $A$ would be lower than both of the other 2 distributions.

##### UPDATE:

Based on some internet research, this problem seems to be very similar to stochastic lexicographic dominance and/or conjoint analysis.  I'm not sure if that helps with ideas for a solution.

Comment: Have a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/417079/weighted-pairwise-comparison-with-table-like-heterogeneous-data-is-bradley-ter. Especially Bradley Terry model

Comment: Thanks @GeorgM.Goerg, I'm looking into the Bradley Terry model now.  I really appreciate the direction; it looks promising :)